# How to complete some task on click of a button and then navigate to a different page?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a winform app which is controlling a website. On click of a button in winform app i want to fill a form, click the submit button on the web page  upon which a new page will open , on that page i have to click on a link.

How to achieve this. i have tried many things but did not got any proper solution

Comment: Something is not clear here. You want a Windows app to open a new website app url?

Comment: no in when i click a button on my form on that these things would happen 1) a form would be filled 2) a button will be clicked 3) on click of that button the website would nvigate to next page, on that next page there is a link which i want to press. this third part is not clear and i am not able to perform this.

Comment: What form? I think you might be confusing WinForms with WebForms.

Comment: @ Tejs i am making a winform , which is controlling the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a web automation tool, use [Watin](http://watin.org/). It allows you to automate via code the opening of a browser, the clicking of buttons, and the fillout of form fields. However, that is more of a testing library.

Honestly though, your choice of solution sounds odd. You're trying to get a client application to make requests through a web page, instead of directly requesting whatever resource yourself from the client application. It's hard to give you a direct solution without a good understanding of the problem space.

Comment: @ Tejs let me make it more simpler . All i want is on click of a win form button a button is clicked on webpage , which will make the page to navigate to a second page , on this second page there is a link which i want to click. but when i do this nothing happens